# How to have fixed spacing in the beginning of wrapped line

Tags: android

Currently, I have the following UI

[image]

I wasn't particular happy with the outcome yet. Instead of having

```
[x] Go to school on
Monday and grab
some sandwich
```

I would like it to look like

```
[x] Go to school on
    Monday and grab
    some sandwich
```

It should be something which looks like in Google Keep

[image]

Right now, I achieve my current UI effect, via the following code.

```
SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

for (Checklist uncheckedChecklist : uncheckedChecklists) {
    spannableStringBuilder.append("\u2610 ").append(uncheckedChecklist.getText()).append("\n");
}

for (Checklist checkedChecklist : checkedChecklists) {
    spannableStringBuilder.append("\u2611 ");
    int start = spannableStringBuilder.length();
    final String text = checkedChecklist.getText();
    spannableStringBuilder.append(text);
    StrikethroughSpan strikethroughSpan = new StrikethroughSpan();
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(strikethroughSpan, start, start+text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    spannableStringBuilder.append("\n");
}
```

**May I know, how can I have fixed spacing in the beginning of wrapped line?**

Comment: I tried a normal checklist with and added a `\n`, it was working fine and it wasn't going on a new line. (try to put the layout of the checklist here). I'm guessing you need a custom view if this wont work.